# How to type the tilde character that is not in my keyboard layout?

Tags: windows, keyboard, backticks

I'm using Windows 7 system with an Italian keyboard layout

[image: italian layout]

As you can see this layout miss the tilde `~` character and the backtick character.
Btw backtick is not so important because I can emulate it in bash script using `$(` and `)`.
The problem is that every time I need the tilde I have to hold Alt and type 1 2 6 (i.e. its ASCII code), it's boring!
And I need it not only in CygWin, but also in GNU R, in eclipse, and much more.

Have you have had this problem with an not-US layout?
Is there any fastest way to type the tilde?

Comment: Personally I'd just buy a US or UK keyboard and be done with it. Or just configure your machine to have a US or UK layout and put stickers on the keys that differ. Also, this is off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Second that. Set the keyboard's locale to international and you will gain the tilde. Just do not look at the keyboard while typing, since it may get confusing. -- ALternatively you might remap a key which rarely gets used (e.g. capslock, or the windows key).

Comment: Advice to programmers: my touchtyping teacher told me to use all the time my native (Czech) keyboard and to learn entering all the special characters from there (mostly using AltGr, sometime Alt-<number>) without swapping keyboard layouts, as it keeps complexity of the typing to the minimum. I was hesitant but followed it and must say it is really great way to go (using it for more than 3 years, programming daily).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651.aspx there's a layout called "Italian (142)", which has ` and ~ accessible via AltGr.

Comment: However this keyboard have different positions for # and @ characters

Answer (score 2):

**WINDOWS 7:**

with italian keyboard follow these steps:

1) press Alt (the one on the left of the spacebar)

2) press 1, 2 and 6 in the numeric keypad

3) release Alt

and finally "~" will appear.

**UBUNTU (tried on 14.04)**:

press AltGr + "ì" (accented i = ì)

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'TyperTask' and create a set of key-strokes, lets say ***ºtilde*** to trigger **~** (tilde):

```
ºtilde=~
```

'TyperTask' Source: http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php

'TyperTask' Portable: http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/typertask-portable